# Getting 'Series' object has no attribute 'isnumeric' while filtering data in pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I  have dataframe like below . I am trying filter out words based on

1)if length of string in Root Word column is equal to 1

2)if Similar_word corresponding Root_word column is blank

3)Remove rows from the dataframe if Text column contains only number

```
Root Word           Similar Word
    kwun             kwung, kwon, kuwan, ton, tong., jwun, stkwun, rd.kl, kuwn, 
    bay              ba
    1   
    chung             chung., cont, kway, containe, kwai, terminal4
    international   
    tin               ti
    floor            floor.
    central          cental, central.
    tsuen           tusen, tsven
    g               gf g/f
```

**My code**

```
similar = [[item[0] for item in model.wv.most_similar(word) if item[1] > 0.7] for word in words]
similarity_matrix = pd.DataFrame({'Root_Word': words, 'Similar_Words': similar})
similarity_matrix = similarity_matrix[['Root_Word', 'Similar_Words']]         
import numpy as np
conditions = [
   similarity_matrix ['Similar_Words'].isnull(),
   similarity_matrix ['Root_Word'].isnumeric(),
similarity_matrix ['Root_Word'].str.len() == 1
]
similarity_matrix  = similarity_matrix [np.logical_or.reduce(conditions)]
```

But I am getting below error

```
AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   3079             if name in self._info_axis:
   3080                 return self[name]
-> 3081             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3082 
   3083     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'
```

How can I fix this.

**Data link**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F6Z3QrOFtAChpPhaMKGu3iJ0epfqKE7F/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `str` ancestor - [`Series.str.isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) and invert final boolean mask by `~`:

```
similarity_matrix ['Root_Word'].astype(str).str.isnumeric()
similarity_matrix ['Similar_Words'] =="",
```

Added condition for remove empty spaces

---

```
    import numpy as np
conditions = [
 similarity_matrix ['Similar_Words'].isnull(),
 similarity_matrix ['Similar_Words'] =="",
 similarity_matrix ['Root_Word'].astype(str).str.isnumeric(),
 similarity_matrix ['Root_Word'].str.len() == 1
]
similarity  = similarity_matrix [~np.logical_or.reduce(conditions)]
    print (similarity_matrix)
      Root_Word                                      Similar_Words
    0      kwun  kwung, kwon, kuwan, ton, tong., jwun, stkwun, ...
    1       bay                                                 ba
    3     chung      chung., cont, kway, containe, kwai, terminal4
    5       tin                                                 ti
    6     floor                                             floor.
    7   central                                   cental, central.
    8     tsuen                                       tusen, tsven

Test all filter out rows:

    print (similarity_matrix [np.logical_or.reduce(conditions)])
           Root_Word Similar_Words
    2              1          None
    4  international          None
    9              g        gf g/f
```

Comment: when I ran this all my words became numerical. I am not getting desired output

Comment: Can you check it now?

Comment: ,now all words in the dataframe are gone

Comment: I edit answer with your data, for me it working nice. Si if some problem it seems data issue.

Comment: @Jezreal, I added the data i am using in the question, but for me its not working

Comment: You need change `similarity_matrix ['Root_Word'].str.isnumeric()` to `similarity_matrix ['Root_Word'].astype(str).str.isnumeric()`

Comment: now it ran. But  null condition is not working always. Similar_word corresponding Root_word column is blank then delete that row

Comment: Not sure if understand, but first condition `similarity_matrix ['Similar_Words'].isnull()` means drop all rows where are `NaN`s in column `Similar_Words`. Can you explain more?

Comment: All rows which having entries in the Similar Words. Then the row should be dropped. Check words 'room,'unit'. those rows are not dropped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163057/discussion-between-rahul-rajan-and-jezrael).

Comment: So problem is `similar = [[item[0] for item in model.wv.most_similar(word) if item[1] > 0.7] for word in words]` nort working?

Comment: All rows which having entries in the Similar Words. Then the row should be dropped. Check words 'room,'unit'. those rows are not dropped.